# I want to test flash on my ASP.NET 3.5 website - any info on how i can?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, vb.net, flash

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 and i am busy setting up a test site for the administrators to see if they can host my ASP.NET site with no problems. I have all ready added some Ajax and Session variables and now i want to add some flash in there as well.
I have NO CLUE how to use it and where to start. Would i be able to just get some flash HTML and place it in my page? Can someone please give me some flash code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice little tutorial on adding Flash to an ASP.NET page over at [Grab Attention with this Free Custom Flasher Control](http://steveorr.net/articles/Flasher.aspx).  He goes through the basics of how to modify the HTML and then a bit more advanced stuff.

Just as a side note, you should consider [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) instead of Flash.

Comment: Thanks, i have to stick with flash since the web designers only know plaint HTML and flash.